# How do I insert a dataset value to a BIRT report outside of a table / cube?

Tags: reporting-services, birt

okay, this has got to be simple - but I can't seem to find an answer...

I am creating a summary report (using BIRT 2.6.1), and laying out a few specific summary values in a grid (not a table or a cube).

Say it's a simple query:

```
SELECT decision FROM dataTable
```

I created a data binding / aggregation (named "sumDecision") on my grid, of a type count, where my expression is:

```
dataSetRow["decision"]
```

Now, I've tried to insert this into a grid, either as "data" or "dynamic text" with the column binding:

```
row["sumDecision"]
```

But when I run the report, it comes up blank.  How would I do this?  Using dataSet["decision"] doesn't seem to do anything either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a Text Item (not Dynamic Text, just Text) and use the "Value Of" tags on the text item.  This will give you an expression editor and as long as your grid is bound to the data set in question, you will be able to choose your data element there.

Since you just want to see the text in the grid, make sure and choose "HTML" for the format of the text item.

Comment: Thanks - when I reviewed my grid, I wasn't binding the dataset to my grid correctly.  Once I did that, I could add both a text item, and an aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to create a table of 1 column, 1 detail - then delete the detail & header rows, and create my grid inside the footer of the table.

From here, I can add a dataset to the table, and create aggregations that work to my hearts content.

Is this the right way to do this, or am I missing something?

Comment: I was missing something - you don't need a table for the data binding, I was just adding the dataset incorrectly.  The correct way is to click on the grid, and under the property editor / binding tab  set the data set... then aggregations work.